# How to insert bulk data to postgresql db from CSV file?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv, sequelize-cli

I have to insert more than 100 records which are present in CSV file to PostgreSQL db. So I have tried the below mentioned code, it is reading the data from the file but unable to insert them to PostgreSQL table so is there any other way to perform this? Like csvtojson etc.?

```
const csv = require('csv');
var csvParser = require('csv-parse');

Controller.uploadCsv = async(data) => {
    fs.createReadStream(data.path)
        .pipe(csvParser({
            delimiter: '\t', 
            endLine: '\n', 
            escapeChar: '"', 
            enclosedChar: '"'
        }))
        .on('data', function(data) {
             console.log(data)// returning in console mentioned below
             console.log(data.name) // is undefined 

             const add = {
                name: data.name,
                address: data.address,
                phoneNo: data.phoneNumber,
                email: data.email,
                created_at: new Date(),
                updated_at: new Date()
            };
            const result = await models.table.create(add);
        })
        .on('end', function(data) {
             console.log('reading finished')
        })
}
```

router.js

```
router.post('/file', upload.single('file'),(req, res, next) => {
    Controller.uploadCsv(req.file)
        .then((result) => res.json(result))
        .catch(next)
})
```

console data

```
    [ 'name',
      'address'
      'phoneNumber',
      'email',
      'created_at',
      'updated_at']
    [ 'aaa',
      'delhi',
      '1102558888',
      'test@gmail.com',
      '2017-10-08T06:17:09.922Z',
      '2018-10-08T06:17:09.922Z',]
    [ 'Oreo',
      'bgl',
      '1112589633',
      'test123@gmail.com',
      '2017-10-08T06:17:09.922Z',
      '2018-10-08T06:17:09.922Z' ]
```

Comment: Do you have to do this through code?  Can you not just pop open pgAdmin and import it that way?  It's 10000% easier...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400173/how-should-i-import-data-from-csv-into-a-postgres-table-using-pgadmin-3

Comment: you can use `psql` instead too. (e.g. `psql -h $SERVER_IP -d $DB -U $USERNAME -c "\copy tmp_special_phrases(word,Key,Value,Plural)  from './special_phrases.csv' with delimiter as ',' CSV HEADER"
`)

Comment: @dvsoukup It has to be done via code only not from pgAdmin panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the **async** keyword on the OnData function. Remember, it's not sequencial execution, so the records may be inserted on a completely diferent order between one program execution and another.

Replace:

```
.on('data', function(data) {
```

With:

```
.on('data', async function(data) {
```

Comment: Remember this will also lead to high memory usage, since the postgre pool will hold back most of the queries. The `on('data')` event handler is not asynchronous and will not wait for execution of the `async` function before emitting more events. Please see my answer for a solution that reads only the needed portion of data before inserting it to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

***TL;DR.*** Your code has a minor error that may be causing your problem - it's when you use await, in order to run it you'd need to put `async` before the `function` on the `data` handler - it may work for small files, but *please read on it's not the right solution - I added one of the proper ways below*.

ES6 async/await is a language construct that allows you to `await` for resolution of a Promise and continue executing the code in an `async` function. In your code you do have an `async function` declaration, however you added `await` in a non-async function. To clarify - `await` keyword will only be allowed when the closest `function() {` is `async` - in your case it's not.

I actually don't think your code would even compile and after some changes you'd fall straight to a problem mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52609647/3790725) - this is because you're trying to run an asynchronous operation on a synchronous event handler in node. This asynchronous insert to the database will get run, but the `end` event **will fire before the operations are completed**.

In order to do this correctly - you could use a transform stream or abandon streaming altogether and simply use an array from CSV (there's more than enough good modules for that). I am however the author of the [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) framework and I also think this should simply work as you wrote it, or maybe even simpler.

Here's a code that will do what you want:

```
const {StringStream} = require('scramjet');

Controller.uploadCsv = async(data) => 
    fs.createReadStream(data.path)
        .pipe(new StringStream('utf-8'))
        .CSVParse({
            delimiter: '\t', 
            newline: '\n', 
            escapeChar: '"', 
            quoteChar: '"'
        })
        .map(data => ({
            name: data.name,
            address: data.address,
            phoneNo: data.phoneNumber,
            email: data.email,
            created_at: new Date(),
            updated_at: new Date()
        }))
        .each(async entry => await models.table.create(entry))
        .each(result => log(result)) // if it's worth logging
        .run();
```

Scramjet simply uses streams (all classes extend built-in node.js streams) underneath, but exposes an interface similar to synchronous ones on Array etc. You can run your async operations and it returns a Promise from `run` operation.